# Jump-Point searching in detail

Tags: artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

I have been trying to implement jump-point search to my already implemented A* pathfinding code, but I don't fully understand how it works. The website [here](http://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/jump-point-search/) (which is all that I could find on it) doesn't really explain much about how to prune or how to determine a jump-point successor. Could anyone explain these two things in detail?

Comment: Did you try to read D. Harabor and A. Grastien. Online Graph Pruning for Pathfinding on Grid Maps. In National Conference on Artificial Intelligence (AAAI), 2011?  It states that the details are in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical details are in the research paper, which can be found on [Alban Grastien's web page](http://grastien.net/ban/articles/hg-aaai11.pdf).

There is also a tutorial on [aigamedev.com](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/symmetry-in-pathfinding/).

It appears that an improved paper will appear at [ICAPS 2014](http://icaps14.icaps-conference.org/technical/papers.html), but I don't believe the papers are online yet.

If these resources are insufficient, a more directed question (what don't you understand) will be easier to answer. But, one thing important to note is that JPS scans the state space looking for obstacles. In doing so it may look at far more states than A* does. But, its time savings come from not putting most states in the OPEN list.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't see the link to the online paper earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the original 2011 paper, I also found this site: https://zerowidth.com/2013/a-visual-explanation-of-jump-point-search.html particularly helpful, as it explains how JPS works in simple terms with diagrams, and also includes a grid where you can add/remove obstacles and visualize how JPS finds and expands jump points.